# Determine number of nodes in a binary tree based on their number of children

Tags: java, binary-tree, nodes

> Your are given the root node of a binary tree *T*. We distinguish between three types of nodes in *T*: nodes with 0 children (i. e., leaves), nodes with 1 child, and nodes with two children. Determine for each type, the total number of nodes in *T*. Return your result as an integer array of length 3.

The output should be an array having a count of all types of nodes as above.

This is what I have but it is not passing my instructor's test when I run it:

```
private static int[] problem1(Node root){

     int[] nodeCount = new int[]{0,0,0};

     // BASE CASE
     if (root == null) {

        // Implement me!
        return new int[] {
           -1, // nodes with 0 children
           -1, // nodes with 1 child
           -1  // nodes with 2 children
        };

     }

     // RECURSIVE CALL
     int[] leftChild = problem1(root.left);
     int[] rightChild = problem1(root.right);

     nodeCount[0] = leftChild[0] + rightChild[0];
     nodeCount[1] = leftChild[1] + rightChild[1];
     nodeCount[2] = leftChild[2] + rightChild[2];

     if(root.left != null && root.right != null) {

        nodeCount[2]++;
        problem1(root.left);
        problem1(root.right);

     }else if(root.left != null && root.right == null) {

        nodeCount[1]++;
        problem1(root.left);

     }else if(root.left == null && root.right != null) {

        nodeCount[1]++;
        problem1(root.right);

     }else {

        nodeCount[0]++;
     }

     return nodeCount;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Please add more detail to your question, and tag the language you are using if you want help in a particular language.  Stackoverflow is not a place just to have others do your homework.  Please provide some example of how you are going about solving the problem and maybe others can help fill in the blank spots.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ptpatersin - my instructor writes all the code to test this method and we are not allowed to alter it, there can't be any helper methods to make this cleaner code, so I don't even know where to start

Comment: @DevChauhan: thank you for wanting to edit questions here. I have reverted your edit though - the statement you edited was clearly copy-pasted from a homework problem. These should be left untouched, since that is exactly what the question author is reading.

Comment: Hi Jay. We don't change questions into answers here, since it would make no sense to future readers what the problem was. Thanks for wanting to add an answer - could you add it below? Click the "Answer Your Question" button.

Comment: Your code has a comment "implement me", meaning it is not complete because there is part you haven't implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing rough code, please check whether it solves your problem:

```
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();

    // For now, 0 key having a count of leaf nodes, 1 key count of nodes having a single child, 2 for both 
    // Use inorder, pre or post to traverse the tree... use countNodes to get count
    // I have used hashmap to keep count, you can take an array as well.

   public void inorder(TreeNode root){
       if(root == null) return;
       inorder(root.left);
       countNodes(root);
      inorder(root.right);
    }

  public void countNodes(TreeNode root){
       if(root == null) return;
       else if(root.left != null && root.right != null){
         count.put(2, 1 + count.getOrDefault(2,0));
       } 
      else if(root.left == null && root.right == null){
         count.put(0, 1 + count.getOrDefault(0,0));
       } 
      else{
         count.put(1, 1 + count.getOrDefault(1,0));
      } 
    }
```

Comment: I am still a beginner so I have not learned about hash maps and my instructor is not allowing any helper methods to make this method cleaner so this unfortunately won't work but thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that every time a null node is called every element of the array is -1. This code will give the right answer:

```
private static int[] problem1(Node root){
    // Implement me!

    //initialize arrays
    int[] nodeCount = {0,0,0};
    int[] n1 = new int[3];
    int[] n2 = new int[3];

    //2 children case
    if(root.left != null && root.right != null){
        n1 = problem1(root.left);
        n2 = problem1(root.right);
        nodeCount[0] += n1[0] + n2[0];
        nodeCount[1] += n1[1] + n2[1];
        nodeCount[2] += n1[2] + n2[2];
        nodeCount[2]++;
        return nodeCount;           
    }

    //leaf case
    if(root.left == null && root.right == null){
        return new int[] {1,0,0};
    }

    //only right child 
    if (root.left == null && root.right != null){
        n1 = problem1(root.right);
        nodeCount[0] += n1[0];
        nodeCount[1] += n1[1];
        nodeCount[2] += n1[2];
        nodeCount[1]++;
        return nodeCount;
    }

    //only left child
    if (root.left != null && root.right == null){
        n1 = problem1(root.left);
        nodeCount[0] += n1[0];
        nodeCount[1] += n1[1];
        nodeCount[2] += n1[2];
        nodeCount[1]++;
        return nodeCount;
    }

   //should never run unless null node is given at start  
   else{
       return new int[] {
           -1, // nodes with 0 children
           -1, // nodes with 1 child
           -1  // nodes with 2 children
       };
    }
}
```